# Regex matching only floating point numbers in a long text

Tags: regex

I have a syntax highlighter which accepts a simple regular expressions to apply a style. Now I need to provide regular expression matching only floating point numbers.

Text sample:

```
test1 -1 0 test2-1.1 0.123 -0.23 255 10.1 1-1-100.11-2
```

What should be matched:
[-1], [0], [0.123], [-0.23] [255], [10.1]

As you can see - the Stack Overflow's highlighter got it wrong :) The last expression is an identifier (could be even a file name). It is definitely not a number.

It's very important no other character from the input text should be matched.

I can't make any replacements to the text. Numbers are separated from the rest of the text with whitespace or semicolon. But those characters cannot be matched.

Obvious attempt:

```
\b[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+\b
```

But this doesn't work. Problem with the "word boundary". The "-" character is treated as non-word character, so first "\b" won't match any negative number. The last "\b" will match before every "-" in text, so in "1-test" "1" would be matched as number, which is wrong.

Is there a smarter anchor working as "\b" but treating "-" as a part of possible word?

I'm afraid there's no solution to this - at least using a single regular expression.
Or am I wrong and it **can** be done?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: C#, but does it matter? The highlighter interface accepts only single Regex object for a single style, and it doesn't use capture groups to ignore parts. If it can't be done with one Regex at all, I'll consider fixing the highlighter. The highlighter is in a PM package, so I would rather avoid making any changes to it.

Comment: Yes it matters. because it can be solved using look arounds and there are certain languages which may not fully support look arounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look arounds can be usefull

```
(?<=\s)[+-]?[\d.]+(?=\s|$)
```

For example:

http://regex101.com/r/yE9uJ4/1

Comment: Thanks. It's an optimized version of the previous answer. And TIL about regex101.com :) Gee, so many years in IT and I haven't known this...

Comment: @Harry you are always welcome :) Glad to hear that i was of some help :)

Comment: This regex also matches `-5.` which is not a valid floating number

Comment: @anubhava yeah i thought of that too. But should the regex be that specific since we have some valid knowledge on the input string

Comment: OP was attempting `\b[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+\b` instead of `\b[-+]?[.\d]+\b` so my guess is that OP's intent was to capture valid floating point numbers only.

Comment: @anubhava :/ should i remove it??

Comment: No-no, don't delete the answer. Just rollback last few edits to keep the original one (which was accepted by OP)

Comment: @anubhava OK will do. And thank you for the tips :) Just started learning

Comment: Never mind small glitches in this or that regex. The rule is powerful enough to make syntax highlighting super easy :) Oh, and I'll surely use this in parser too. Of course I used to write parsers and highlighters before, but they were so unnecessarily complex without look arounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
(?<= |^)[-+]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?= |$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY4eC5/1)